# shifting elements in an array of strings and fill with zeros

Tags: c, arrays

I want to shift elements in my array to right and fill the shifted elements with zero (as string) . but it's a bit more difficult than i thought.

this program reads a text file containing two lines. each line contains of an integer (maximum length is defined). it saves each line in a separate array.

I need to convert these two arrays to integer array later and do some arithmetic operations.

so for that, i need to make sure that these two arrays have the same length

for example my input is:

num_first : **1859654**

num_second: **5654**

now i need them to be:

num_First : **1859654** (it's larger than second number so it doesn't change)

num second: **0005654** (smaller than first, so we need to add those **leading zeros**)

**how do i add those leading zeros to array based on difference of two input??**

and at last i want to save them in arrays (as string or integer).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE_MAX 20

int main()
{

FILE *fPTR;

    char num_first[SIZE_MAX]; // string input
    char num_second[SIZE_MAX];

    if ((fPTR = fopen("input.txt", "r")) == NULL) // our file contains two line of integers. one at each
    {
        puts("File could not be opened.");
    }
    else
    {
        if (fgets(num_first, SIZE_MAX, fPTR) != NULL) // reads first line and saves to num_first
            puts(num_first); // prints first number
        if (fgets(num_second, SIZE_MAX, fPTR) != NULL) // reads second line and saves to num_second
            puts(num_second); // prints second number
        fclose(fPTR);
    }

    // getting strings lengths
    int fLEN = strlen(num_first) - 1;
    int sLEN = strlen(num_second);


    int e = 0; // difference between two string lengths

    // here we get the difference and it's the place which i want to shif the arrays

    if (fLEN>sLEN) // first string is bigger than second
    {
        e = fLEN-sLEN;
    }
    else if (sLEN>fLEN) // second string is bigger than first
    {
        e = sLEN-fLEN;
    }
    else // there is no difference between two strings
    {
        e = fLEN-sLEN;
    }

}
```

**edit:** i also got another idea but it doesn't work as intended.

```
if (fLEN>sLEN) // first string is bigger than second
    {
        e = fLEN-sLEN;
        for(i=e;i>=0;i--)
        {
            num_second[i+1] = num_second[i];
        }
        for(i=fLEN-e;i>=0;i--)
        {
            num_second[i] = '0';
        }
    }
```

edit 2: (slowly started to working) prints more zero. trying to fix it

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE_MAX 20

int main()
{

FILE *fPTR;

    char num_first[SIZE_MAX]; // string input
    char num_second[SIZE_MAX];
    char num_second2[SIZE_MAX] = {0};
    int i = 0;
    char numbers[SIZE_MAX];

    if ((fPTR = fopen("input.txt", "r")) == NULL) // our file contains two line of integers. one at each
    {
        puts("File could not be opened.");
    }
    else
    {
        if (fgets(num_first, SIZE_MAX, fPTR) != NULL) // reads first line and saves to num_first
            puts(num_first); // prints first number
        if (fgets(num_second, SIZE_MAX, fPTR) != NULL) // reads second line and saves to num_second
            puts(num_second); // prints second number
        fclose(fPTR);
    }

    // getting strings lengths
    int fLEN = strlen(num_first) - 1;
    int sLEN = strlen(num_second);


    int e = 0; // difference between two string lengths
    int h = 4;

    // here we get the difference and it's the place which i want to shif the arrays

    if (fLEN>sLEN) // first string is bigger than second
    {
        e = fLEN-sLEN;
        while (i>= h)//for(i=e;i>=0;i--)
        {
            num_second2[i+h] = num_second[i];
            i++;
            h--;
        }
        for(i=fLEN-e;i>=0;i--)
        {
        //  num_second[i] = '0';
        }
    }
    else if (sLEN>fLEN) // second string is bigger than first
    {
        e = sLEN-fLEN;
    }
    else // there is no difference between two strings
    {
        e = fLEN-sLEN;
    }
    printf("\n%d\n", e);
        for (i = 0; i < SIZE_MAX; i++) // using c to print
    {
        printf("%d", num_second2[i]);
    }
    puts(num_second);
}
```

Comment: so what's your question ? Unless you provide a clear question, you can do  the rest yourself.

Comment: edited. i want to add those leading zeros based on difference of input numbers.

Comment: [strcat](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) or [sprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) could be of use to you

Comment: it would be very appreciated if you could provide a solution and use it in the code then share it. also i don't want to print anything. i just want to add leading zeros then save to  array.

Comment: @vvvsg in C an array of char or a string is almost the same, and very much the same in your case. the goal of my comment was to help you solving the problem yourself, rather than providing a straight answer that would have helped you less.

Comment: @dvhh I have spent so much time already trying to figure this out but so far didn't succeed. that's why a working code would be better in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE_MAX 20

int main()
{

    FILE *fPTR;

    char num_first[SIZE_MAX]; // string input
    char num_second[SIZE_MAX];
    char num_zeros[SIZE_MAX];//array for leading zeros
    int i = 0;
    char numbers[SIZE_MAX];

    if ((fPTR = fopen("input.txt", "r")) == NULL) // our file contains two line of integers. one at each
    {
        puts("File could not be opened.");
    }
    else
    {
        if (fgets(num_first, SIZE_MAX, fPTR) != NULL) // reads first line and saves to num_first
            puts(num_first); // prints first number
        if (fgets(num_second, SIZE_MAX, fPTR) != NULL) // reads second line and saves to num_second
            puts(num_second); // prints second number
        fclose(fPTR);
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < SIZE_MAX; i++)
    {
        num_zeros[i] = '0';//fill array with '0's
    }
    // getting strings lengths
    int fLEN = strlen(num_first);
    if ( fLEN && num_first[fLEN - 1] == '\n')
    {
        num_first[fLEN - 1] = '\0';//remove trailing newline
        fLEN--;
    }
    int sLEN = strlen(num_second);
    if ( sLEN && num_second[sLEN - 1] == '\n')
    {
        num_second[sLEN - 1] = '\0';//remove trailing newline
        sLEN--;
    }
    int e = 0; // difference between two string lengths
    // here we get the difference and it's the place which i want to shif the arrays
    if (fLEN>sLEN) // first string is bigger than second
    {
        e = fLEN-sLEN;
        num_zeros[e] = '\0';//terminate array leaving e leading zeros
        strcat ( num_zeros, num_second);
        strcpy ( num_second, num_zeros);
    }
    else if (sLEN>fLEN) // second string is bigger than first
    {
        e = sLEN-fLEN;
        while ( fLEN >= 0)//start at end of array
        {
            num_first[fLEN + e] = num_first[fLEN];//copy each element e items from current location
            fLEN--;// decrement length
        }
        while ( e)// number of leading zeros
        {
            e--;
            num_first[e] = '0';// set first e elements to '0'
        }
    }
    else // there is no difference between two strings
    {
        //e = fLEN-sLEN;
    }
    puts(num_first);
    puts(num_second);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Good start with your code.

Since you're reading strings you can just use string manipulation.
If you wanted to read them as ints you could determine the size with a logarithm function, but that would be overkill.

You *could* save the numbers as ints, but then you'd have to defer the padding until you printed them later or saved them to a file.

The easiest way to left pad the numbers with zeroes would be to use sprintf()  with the correct format specifier to right justify the number.  **Then you can iterate through each character of the result and replace space e.g. ' ' with '0**'.  That will create left-side 0-padded entries.  E.g. sprintf right justifies your number in a buffer that has room to hold the max sized number you can read, leaving spaces on the left.

Then in a loop indexing one character at a time in the entry, and based on MAX_NUMBER_LEN shown below, you skip extra spaces on the left you don't want zeroes in (e.g. MAX_NUMBER_LEN - maxPaddingLenYouCalculateAtRuntime), and start replacing with zeroes.

Then it's just a matter of creating a buffer whose address you'll pass to sprintf() that has enough space allocated to hold the result. That will have to be as big or bigger than your max length. I would call it maxStrLen rather than e, because naming variables for what they're used for makes for an easier to understand and maintain program.

You have a few choices as to how to allocate that buffer of the right size, including using malloc().  But it is probably easier to determine the maximum size that an integer could be. There's even a C constant that tells you what a 32-bit or 64 bit Integer max. value is, and create an char array of fixed length entries based on that size in advance.

For example:

```
#define MAX_ENTRIES = 10
#define MAX_NUMBER_LEN = 15
char numbers[MAX_ENTRIES][MAX_NUMBER_LEN]
```

That would give you the storage to store your sprintf() results in.
Example:

```
sprintf(numbers[entryNumber], "*right-justifying format specifier you look up*", numberReadFromFile)
```

Wherein entryNumber is which slot in the array you want to store the result.

The MAX_NUMBER_LEN part you *don't* need to include when getting the address for sprintf (notice I just passed in numbers[entryNumber], but not the 2nd set of brackets, intentionally). Because by omitting the second set of brackets, you're saying you want the address of the specific [MAX_NUMBER_LEN] chunk corresponding to the entryNumber, inside the numbers array.  Note, there is no **&** on numberReadFromFile either, because you are reading them into a char *array* as strings, and because you're passing the address of the first char of an array you can just pass the array name. Alternatively you could pass in &numberReadFromFile[0] to get the address of the first element to pass to sprintf().

And when using arrays *that* way, you don't need the **&** character to get the variable address to pass to sprintf(), as you would if you were not passing in an array element,  because arrays really are simply another *notation* for *pointers* in C, and understanding how that works in general is the key to being effective with C in general and worth the initial struggle to comprehend.

Here's an example of how to do the actual zero padding, based on what you got into your array from sprintf.  I won't code up a full example because learning C is about the struggle to actually do it yourself.  There's no shortcut to real comprehension.  I'm giving you the hardest to discover aspects, by you working it through and making a solution of it, you'll gain quite a bit of mastery.  This code is off the top of my head, not compiled and tested. It would either work or be close to working.

```
/* numberToPad is a buffer containing a right-justified number, e.g. a number
 * shifted-right by sprintf(), in a buffer sized 15 characters,
 * space-padded on the left by sprintf's right-justifying format specifier.       
 * We want to convert the number to a 10-digit zero-padded number
 * inside a 15 character field. The result should be 4 spaces, followed
 * by some zeroes, followed by non-zero digits, followed by null-terminator.
 * example: "ƀƀƀƀ0000012345\0" where ƀ is a space character.
 */

#define MAX_NUMBER_LEN 15  /* note: 15 includes null-terminator of string */
int maxNumberLenActuallyRead = 10;
int startZeroPaddingPos = MAX_NUMBER_LEN - maxNumberLenActuallyRead
char numberToPad[MAX_NUMBER_LEN]; 
int i;
for (i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_LEN; i++) {
    if (i < startZeroPaddingPos) 
        continue;
    if (numberToPad[i] == ' ')
        numberToPad[i] = '0';         
}
```

Comment: thanks for it. a few questions: 1- is numbers[entryNumber] the array to store results? 2- how exactly i use right-justifying and filling with zero?  a working complete code would do the job. thanks edit: also in define there shouldn't be = sign

Comment: I've been editing the hell out of it but I'm done for now. Go ahead, ask questions. I'll keep checking back and try to help.

Comment: 1. yes.  2.  you need a for loop that walks thru each character of the char but and compares it to ' ' (space) and replaces *some* w/'0'. I say some because you may have made the array [MAX_NUMBER_SIZE] field *wider* than you actually want to pad with zeroes.  Because it was a compile-time choices to size the array, but the actual padding size is dependent on the max size of numbers you actually read. 3.   #define is a compile time pre-processor directive to define constants, not variables and doesn't use '='.  I will toss in a small example of how to loop through a char array.

Comment: @1sand0s note that there is a printf specifier to pad with '0'

Comment: If you convert the number to an int there may be, I know how to do it for floats, not sure how to left-pad with zeroes for numbers. That would be a good thing to look for in the sprintf() format specifier options.

Comment: Added example of how to actually swap spaces with zeroes.  Getting it all to go together into a working example may be challenging for a n00b, but it is how you're going to learn and get some mastery.

Comment: @vvvsg, I can't write the code for you, I'm behind at work as it is, plus the real gain is in your struggle to put it all together. No pain, no gain!

Comment: @1s and 0s, what do you think about my solution?  (OP is edited) if you comment out second for loop in it, you see that it can actually move elements. (although not enough) also i expect the second loop to work as intended but it doesn't. your comment and possible fix would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks good. Close to solution. Not sure what's wrong, but I'd advise being consistent in w/strlen() calculation for fLen and and sLen, also camel case means, you wouldn't capitalize all of LEN. Extreme consistency in every way helps prevent and catch a *lot* of bugs. Also, at first programmers tend to not pay attention to formatting, and compress out spaces, etc... but it makes the code denser and much harder to read and maintain in the long run. In the kernel group I was in for a major OS, they were very strict about formatting and consistency because there was so much tough code to maintain.

Comment: I personally have always hated putting { } on separate lines from if () and else.  Some people swear by it and there are two camps. But it just vertically extends code so much so you can't see as much of it in a page and small window. You just can't see as much code as quickly and to me it looks tacky.  More scrolling than necessary and just lanky.

Comment: While you're busy playing games accepting and unaccepting my answer and milking free good will and energy from me for me getting little in return, if your conscience isn't bothering you, you might want to consider the discrepancy of how you've omitted spaces horizontally but added too much space vertically to your code.  Seems like an odd contradiction. Anyway, I'm done with this thread.  I hope you've learned something valuable.